# How to call a function in setup() to a function in methods?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have function in setup() named *onRquest*, I want to call that function in methods after execution of an action(deleting row), which gonna refresh the table. Please check the code segment for better understanding:

```
export default {
  setup() {
      function onRequest(props) {

      }

      onMounted(() => {
          onRequest({
              pagination: pagination.value,
              filter: undefined,
          })
      })

      return {
          onRequest
      }
  },

  methods: {
      deleteBranch(branch_id) {
          this.$q.dialog({
              title: 'Confirm',
              message: 'Would you like to Delete Branch#' + branch_id + '?',
              cancel: true,
              persistent: true
          }).onOk(() => {
              this.$axios.delete('https://api.bdshsystem.com/api/v1/branch/' + 
              branch_id).then(response => {
                  this.$q.notify({
                      type: 'positive',
                      timeout: 500,
                      position: 'top',
                      message: 'Branch Deleted Successfully !'
                  })
```

**I want to put function *onRequest* Here**

```
              }).catch((error) => {
                  this.$q.notify({
                      type: 'negative',
                      position: 'top',
                      timeout: 500,
                      message: 'Form submission Failed !'
                  })
              })
          }).onOk(() => {
          // console.log('>>>> second OK catcher')
          }).onCancel(() => {
          // console.log('>>>> Cancel')
          }).onDismiss(() => {
          // console.log('I am triggered on both OK and Cancel')
          })
      },
  },
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm just curious that why don't you place function `deleteBranch` inside `setup()`?

Answer (score 0):

Insted of passing you method inline i.e. the "setup()" method, directly in export default. define it outside and pass its reference to export default then you can call setup() directly in whatever method you want

```
function setup(){
//some code
}

export default {"setup":setup,
      "yourOtherMethod":function yourOtherMethod(){
      //your other method code here 
}}
```